# How to solve the first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a differential equation:
$$y(x)\frac{dy(x)}{dx}+nxy(x)=C,$$
where $n$ and $C$ are constants. Is there a way to get $y(x)$ ?

Comment: Notice that when $C=0$ then the ode is $y(y'+n)=0$. Then $y=0$ or $y=B-\frac{n}{2}x^2$. Of course the case $C\not=0$ it is more interesting. Mathematica find ugly solutions in terms of special functions. What is the context for your problem?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The ODE was derived from a diffusion equation $u_t=(uu_r)_r$ after using the transformation $x=\frac{r}{t^n}$ and $u=\frac{y}{t^n}$. $C\neq0$. I tried to find a way to transform the ODE into a simpler form, but failed. I have no idea about it now.

Comment: Try a series solution giving any boundary condition. It works.

Comment: What WA gives is not a solution but an implicit equation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, it's a solution in implicit form. I'd like to know how to arrive at that solution.

Answer (score 4):

It's not difficult to see how Wolfram Alpha got its solution.  Rewrite the differential equation as $$\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac C y - n x.$$  We can get a function with a simpler derivative by taking $t:=nx^2+2y$: $$\frac{d t}{d x}=2nx + 2(\frac C y - n x) = \frac{2C} y.$$
Then by the inverse function theorem,
$$\frac{d x}{d t}=\frac{y}{2C} = \frac{t}{4C} - \frac{n}{4C} x^2.$$
This is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) for $x$ with independent variable $t$, so substitute $$x=4C\left.\frac{d z}{d t} \right/ nz$$
to get
$$
\frac{d^2 z}{d t^2} = \frac{n}{16 C^2} t z.
$$
If $t$ is rescaled by $$q:=\left(\frac n {16C^2}\right)^{1/3},$$ this is an Airy equation for $z$, so it has solution $z={\cal A}(qt)$, for $\cal A$ a solution to the [Airy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) (it can be any linear combination of Ai and Bi with constant coefficients.)  Unwinding our substitutions, we get
$$nx {\cal A}(qt)=4 q C {\cal A}'(qt),$$
or
$$nx {\cal A}(q(nx^2+2y))=4 q C {\cal A}'(q(nx^2+2y)).$$
This is the solution given by Wolfram Alpha.  It's an implicit solution,
as it's in the form of an equation involving $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this, and I have a thing for differential equations so I thought I'd jump in - would love to get discussion going!
We have
$$
y(x) \frac{dy(x)}{dx} + nxy(x) = C
$$
Which I'll write
$$
y \frac{dy}{dx} + nxy = C
$$
to save on some keystrokes.

Something that comes to mind is to divide by $y$ such that
$$
y \frac{dy}{dx} + nxy = C \rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} + nx = C\frac{1}{y} = Cg(x) = Cg
$$
Here, I defined $g = g(x) = 1/y(x)$ which I think is a reasonable step as long as we are take into account later on that this is **not valid when $y(x) = 0$**.

But if we continue, we have
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} + nx = Cg
$$
or
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = Cg - nx
$$

This expression is now integrable on both sides, thus
$$
\int \frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int (Cg - nx) dx
$$
$$
= \int dy = y = \int Cg dx - \int nx dx = C\int g(x) dx - \frac{n}{2}x^2 + D
$$
Where $D$ is some other constant that can be determined given a set of favourable initial conditions.
We thus end up with
$$
y(x) = C\int g(x) dx - \frac{n}{2}x^2 + D
$$

Leaving us with

1. If we can integrate $g(x) = 1/y(x)$ then we may get an analytic expression, otherwise numerical routines are needed
2. Remember that the above result is valid when $y(x) \neq 0$
3. Initial conditions will help us fine-tune on a value for $D$

What do yall think?

Comment: You rewrote the ODE as an integral equation. What's the solution to it?